# Finding all possible unique combinations of numbers to reach a given sum

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, backtracking, subset-sum

We have a list of numbers, let's say: [ 2, 3, 5 ]
and we have a targetSum, let's say: 8

Our goal, then, is to pick numbers from the list in such a way that the sum of the numbers would lead to targetSum

I'll explain my code first, I wrote a simple c++ code for the same, it uses recursion and backtracking ( without memoization ). It does the following:

- We subdivide our original problem by reducing the targetSum by each number at each recursion
- Visualizing this in the form of a tree is useful, we also keep track of what number's we have substracted so far, and we keep pushing and popping accordingly
- Once we hit the base case of 0, meaning it's possible to create the sum, we make a note of the current numbers we have recursed
- This process goes on until we have gone through all of the possibilities

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

bool bestSum( int targetSum, vector<int> &holder, vector<vector<int>> &combinations, 
vector<int> &path )
{
    if( targetSum == 0 )
    {
        combinations.push_back( path );
        return true;
    }
    if( targetSum < 0 )
    {
        return false;
    }

    bool possible = false;

    for( int i = 0; i < holder.size(); i++ )
    {
        int remainder = targetSum - holder[i];
        path.push_back(holder[i]);
    
        cout << "After pushing:";
        for( int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++ )
        {
            cout << path[j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    
        bool verdict = bestSum( remainder, holder, combinations, path );
        if( verdict == true )
        {
            possible = true;
        }
    
        path.pop_back();
        cout << "After popping:";
        for( int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++ )
        {
            cout << path[j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    
    }

    return possible;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> holder = { 2, 3, 5 };
    int targetSum = 8;

    vector<vector<int>> combinations;
    vector<int> path;

    bool verdict = bestSum( targetSum, holder, combinations, path );

    for( int i = 0; i < combinations.size(); i++ )
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < combinations[i].size();j++)
        {
            cout << combinations[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(ignoring the printing statements) Talking about time complexity, it should be: exponential, without memoization
And at most small degree polynomial, with memoization

Combing back to the original problem, currently my code produces all of the possible combinations, for example, with the numbers list and targetSum presented at the start of this article, we would get: 2,3,3 and 3,3,2 as two different combinations. But we know that they aren't unique

My question is, is it possible to find all unique combination of numbers whilst keeping the logic of my code consistent?

Comment: Only allow the recursive routine to choose numbers equal to or greater than the last number chosen. Which means, for example, that 2,3,3 is valid, but 3,3,2 and 3,2,3 are not.

Comment: @user3386109 I have one another question, how would i memoize it. See, the issue i am running into is the fact that, i am using backtracking to build the path from the root to each leaf, which means it's a bit messy to get just the lower half of the recursion tree. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it worked :) To memoize, you need to determine the defining characteristics of a subproblem. I would say those are (1) the remaining sum and (2) the index of the last number chosen. A 2D memoization table can be indexed by those two values.

Comment: @user3386109 Here's what i am trying to do, if we encounter a targetSum once again while iterating the rest of the tree we, then, shouldn't have to recurse through it again. I should be able to say "ah, we have seen this targetSum before and i know that paths that lead me to zero from here are, for example, so and so branches. So, i was thinking what if we cache the targetSum and the paths leading from that target sum to zero. But i was facing immense problem cause since we are using backtracking we wouldn't have the path from each node to the leaf. I don't think i understand your approach :(

Comment: Same as the_coin change problem: number of ways of making change for `n` given an array of coin values, so pretty easy to google.